# Multiple SET expressions in query?

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms

Want to update specific data in a Table Column.

I can use the below for one entry:

`UPDATE [BULDING].[dbo].[TB_DATA]

SET OFFICE_ID = '4' where OFFICE__ID = '8';`

But what should I use for multiple entry change - below obviously does not work:

`UPDATE [BULDING].[dbo].[TB_DATA]

SET OFFICE_ID = '4' where OFFICE_ID = '8'

SET OFFICE_ID = '4' where OFFICE_ID = '10'

SET OFFICE_ID = '11' where OFFICE__ID = '3';`

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
UPDATE [BULDING].[dbo].[TB_DATA]
SET OFFICE_ID = 
    case when office_id in ('8', '10') then '4'
        when office_id = '3' then '11'
        else office_id
    end
```